# How to modify a file on a web server without date change (attack)

Tags: javascript, server-side-attacks

I have an attack on a webserver, where i get code injected into my js files. But the date did not change. The attack was 1 month ago, but the file was last modified 2 years ago.

How do you do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "injected into my js files"? Is it possible that the Javascript code was just executed on your site?

Comment: @Andreas I believe this refers to when your server is insecure and someone edits your source code to display ads or do malicious things (bitcoin mining etc).

Comment: FYI - not a javascript problem. I can't mark as a duplicate because this isn't on the same site, but this may shed some light.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43119/preserve-modified-time-stamp-after-edit

Comment: @Dawson thx. So its something my hoster is responsible for it.